# how to make custom component some style extends defult component style?

Tags: material-ui

for example,i installed third party component like rc-tree-select.this component has own css and has "dropdownStyle" props to custom it.

then,if i want set dropdownStyle boxShadow eq MuiPaper default boxShadow, if i usr createTheme to changed MuiPaper.defaultProps.sx.boxShadow value,then dropdownStyle boxShadow will keep the default value.how to do that. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an MUI theme object using [`createTheme`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#api) and then use it like this to get the default shadow of an MUI Paper component.

```ts
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme();

const paperDefaultShadow = theme.shadows[1];

// Use the paperDefaultShadow wherever you want to give the shadow style.
```